# Connecting to Azure Service Bus using MDM SDK Sample Code

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I am using the sample code from the MDM SDK and trying to connect to Azure Queue's.

I am getting the below error while connecting:

> "The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:36.6246411'."

Can someone please help me resolve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the code causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

it was a network issue. got this resolved with my network team. I had to open a port for communication with the portal.

thank you